# What do I do with these eggs?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

What do I do with the eggs that I've been finding in Dungeon Defenders? I've got a couple of different sizes, but I can't seem to upgrade them or anything.

[image]

Do they hatch into something or are they used to sell for mana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collecting a ​certain number of a particular type of eggs awards players with various rewards. Players must return to their own tavern to unlock their rewards. All eggs are consumed in the unlocking process.

```
24 Small Eggs - Squire Bunny Costume
36 Humongous Eggs - Mega Chicken pet
```

It has been confirmed that there is no current use for the Large, Huge and Gigantic eggs other than their sale for mana. [Source](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Egg_%28Easter%29)